# Codeigniter validation errors are not displaying

Tags: php, codeigniter

My codeigniter validation errors are not displaying someone can help?
my code is

```
public function addProduct(){
    $this->load->view('header', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('product/addProduct');
    $this->load->view('footer');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('productName', 'Product Name', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('productPrice', 'Product Price', 'required|trim');
        if (!$this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // some stuff on validation success
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('product/addProduct');
        }

}
```

and i have added 
 echo validation_errors(); in my view and action of the form is product/addProduct.

Comment: Because of you have to pass validation error in your function

Comment: @Nikhil Vaghla i have to pass validation error in another function ?

Comment: remove the first one $this->load->view('product/addProduct');

Comment: use this way      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
           $this->load->view('product/addProduct');
        }
        else{
            // some stuff on validation success
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On view example

```
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>

<!-- lower case for the controller name on form open -->

<?php echo form_open_multipart('product/addProduct');?>

<h5>productName</h5>
<input type="text" name="productName" value="<?php echo set_value('productName'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>productPrice</h5>
<input type="text" name="productPrice" value="<?php echo set_value('productPrice'); ?>" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div> 

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Controller

Make sure your file name and class name is something like this below where first letter only upper case

[Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller)

Filename: Product.php

```
<?php

class Product extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
 }

 public function addProduct(){

    // You can get data from here also

    $this->data['some'] = 'Blah';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('productName', 'Product Name', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('productPrice', 'Product Price', 'required|trim');

    // remove your !

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

        // You can just display view in this area you do not have to load it multiple times

        $this->load->view('header', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('product/addProduct');
        $this->load->view('footer');

    } else {

        // some stuff on validation success
    }

 }

}
```

Also check you have set your base url in config.php is required now in CI3 versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it's work for you.

`form_error()` function return your form error.

```
        $post_fields = $this->input->post();
        $data['msg'] = '<ul>';
        foreach ($post_fields as $k => $v) {
            if (form_error($k))
                $data['msg'] .= "<li>" . strip_tags(form_error($k)) . "</li>\n";
        }
        $data['msg'].='</ul>';
        $this->load->view('product/addProduct',$data);
```

**OR**

```
echo validation_errors();//this function also return form  error.
```

Comment: Thank You . but could you please explain the faults in my code.

Comment: In your code you can not pass error in else part. You need to post your error in your view

Comment: if you have happy with answer then accept answer and upvote.